# How to create scattered points in polygon

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I have few polygons and I want to create few scattered well distributed point within the polygon. I am used to with ArcGIS and QGIS platform. How can I make it?

Answer (score 11):

In QGIS there are two tools you could use, you can find them both in Vector -> Research Tools.  One will create a random set of points in a polygon, the other will create a regular grid.  It sounds like the Regular Points tool will get you what you need.

Answer (score 5):

There are two really easy methods to accomplish this using ArcGIS:

1. Create random points within your polygon using [Create Random Points
       (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002r000000)
2. Creating a regular grid of points within your polygon

---

Method one is fairly straight forward.  Method two requires a few steps:

1. Use [Polygon to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000030000000) making sure your grid is to whatever
   pixel size suits your analysis.  In this example, I used 100m.
2. Convert [Raster to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000007000000) to generate a regular grid within your
   original polygon

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that Create Random Points and Polygon to Raster tools are only available in ArcGIS Advanced or with either the Spatial Analyst or 3D Analyst Extensions.

Comment: Alternative (Basic license) to Polygon To Raster then Raster To Point is Create Fishnet then Clip.

Answer (score 3):

Another good option is the free software, [Geospatial Modelling Environment](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/) (Formerly Hawth's Tools).  Among the large number of vector/raster/analysis tools it contains, there are a number of tools for sampling design including generating points within a polygon.

There is a tool which will generate [regular points within polygons](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/genregularpntsinpolys.htm) and you can even specify an angle of rotation if you want the points to align with something other than East-West/North-South.  There is also a tool which will generate [random points within a polygon](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/genrandompnts.htm).

Comment: +1 For GME.  Keep in mind that GME has ArcGIS and R dependencies.